# Google Spanner Postgres DB fetch Last 5 hours data

Tags: postgresql, intervals, google-cloud-spanner

I have a table with 3 columns Id, Data, Date.
Date has dataType timestamp with time zone.

I want to get last 5 hours created ids Query.
I tried with interval query

```
 Select Id from table where
 date > (current_date - INTERVAL '5 hour')
```

It is showing interval is NOT supported in postgre

How I can query to get Id for last 5 Hour

Comment: Hi @Sneha Mule , I tried to reproduce the error that you came up with but I'm always querying successfully with the sample dataset and query you provide. Could you provide the specific error log when using the query above and also what version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB were you testing on a native PostgreSQL database? The question is about a PostgreSQL interface database in Spanner not a standalone PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, Cloud Spanner's PostgreSQL interface unfortunately doesn't yet support the INTERVAL data type.

But you can do so in your app.  For example, if you're using Python on the application side, do something like:

```python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
t = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=5)
```

Then for your query, do:

```sql
Select Id from table where date > $1
```

and pass `t` in as a query parameter.  (Or as a datetime string-literal, but parameters are safer and faster if this is production code.)